# How do I expand the following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Taking pre-calc and it's been years since I took college algebra,

I need to find the zeros and graph behavior of $f(x) = -3(x-1)^2(x^2-4)$.

I know it's $(-3(x-1)^2)(x+2) (x-2)$, but in order to find the degree of the polynomial, I need to expand which is where I'm currently stuck

The zeros would be $1$, $2$ and $-2$

Comment: It's a fourth degree polynomial. $$\deg((x-1)^2(x^2-4))=\deg(x^2-2x+1)+\deg(x^2-4)=2+2=4$$

Comment: It's a degree four polynomial.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks, I see that it's a 4th degree polynomial by that shortcut method, I was really just curious how to expand it out and do the multiplication.

Comment: Thanks everyone, My last math class was 14  years ago, trying to get back in the swing so I can take calc and calc 2 (eventually)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(x-1)^2(x^2-4)=(x^2-2x+1)(x^2-4)=x^2(x^2-2x+1)-4(x^2-2x+1)=x^4-2x^3+x^2-4x^2+8x-4=x^4-2x^3-3x^2+8x-4$$

Comment: I think you missed the leading -3 but that should be fairly straight forward to do after

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now